# concat(fn:data(value),',') concatenating *all* strings, not just value

Tags: xquery

I need a help in solving an issue with Xquery.

I am using below Xquery to get the "value" of attributes. However there is one attribute "Email" which has further child attributes. SO with below Xquery I am getting data for all the "Value" 
i.e.  truetruebc@hghh.gff, truetruexyn@qwe.com, 39919741
However I need only "abc@hghh.gff $# xyn@qwe.com, 39919741" in my output.

```
{/root/*/attributes/* [ov='true']/fn:concat(fn:data(value),',')}



   <root>
   <_1>
      <attributes>
         <Email>
            <ov>true</ov>
            <value>
               <Email>
                  <ov>true</ov>
                 <value>abc@hghh.gff</value>
               </Email>
            </value>
         </Email>
         <Email>
            <ov>true</ov>
            <value>
               <Email>
                  <ov>true</ov>
                  <value>xyn@qwe.com</value>
               </Email>
            </value>
         </Email>
         <UniqueId>
            <ov>true</ov>
            <value>39919741</value>
         </UniqueId>
      </attributes>
   </_1>
</root>
```

Comment: A question's title should reflect the specific technical question being asked in a manner that distinguishes it from other questions (so someone with their own xquery question can tell from the title if your question is about the same problem, and thus if answers to your question are likely to help them) -- not the nature or urgency of your need for an answer.

Comment: ...and frankly, that question is hard to follow -- for instance, it refers to `Entity1_Value`, `ChildValue1`, etc, but your sample data has none of those. Please see the Help Center's guidance on building a [mcve] to illustrate your problem so others can reproduce it.

Comment: You say the desired output includes "$#". Where is that supposed to come from?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to take the concatenation of those `value` descendant elements that don't have any child elements so you can use e.g. `string-join(/root/*/attributes/*[ov='true']//value[not(*)], ',')`.

In XQuery 3.1 you could also use the [`innermost()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-innermost) function with e.g. `string-join(innermost(/root/*/attributes/*[ov='true']//value), ',')`.

Comment: thanks for providing the answer and it is working now. Do you know the query in case I need output like ": abc@hghh.gff $# xyn@qwe.com, 39919741

Comment: It doesn't makes sense that you edit your question to change the result you want once you got an answer that solved the previous problem description. Ask a new question if you have a new question, even if it is related to the previous one. And explain where the data or format like "$#" comes from when writing the new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
fn:string-join(/root/attributes[ov='true']/*/Value/string(), ",")
```

Comment: @AnjitSharma probably because you put a different XML record in the question and now you are asking for different output from it. For your new record and requested output why not just do root//value/string() and get all the value attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML document isn't well-formed. (XML element names are case-sensitive, so you can't start with `<Value>` and end with `<value>`, for example.) So I fixed that.

Then, I found that your query yields nothing, because it's looking for an element ('*') between `root` and `attributes`, which doesn't exist in the document. So I changed `/*/` to just `/`.

At that point, I got the result of `ENtity1_Value, ENtity2_Value, ENtity3_Value,`. So who knows where `ChildValue1, ChildValue2,` came from. Possibly your *real* query had a `//` in it.

(When you ask a question on StackOverflow, you should ensure that your example behaves as described.)

Comment: i have updated the xml record, hope it is accurate now. With this record, i need output as:  abc@hghh.gff, xyn@qwe.com, 39919741